# Make Django MEDIA_URL arbitrary?

Tags: django, nginx

I have a server that I would like to be accessible from many different addresses:

```
192.168.1.101
mh00h.com (via dd-wrt router)
192.168.100.101 (ip of dd-wrt router, port forwarded to server)
```

If the server is accessed from the 192.168.100.x network, how can I make Django's MEDIA_URL arbitrary such that a PC accessing any of these subnets will be able to access the /media directory?

The server runs gunicorn, django, and nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using the socket lib:

```
import socket

if socket.gethostname() == 'mh00h.com':
    MEDIA_URL = 'foo'
else:
    MEDIA_URL = 'bar'
```

Edit:

I think I misunderstood your question, just write a middleware layer that does your switch logic, or configure nginx if you know all the ip cases beforehand. Btw what is the actual problem you're trying to tackle?

Comment: I want to be able to access the server from different subnets without relying on DNS (so that I don't have to pay for one).